# layout webpage with hidden divs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have a webpage that is mostly hidden divs that I interact with using jquery animations.
I was wondering what the best way to do this.
Some ideas i thought about include just leaving all divs on the page as hidden divs.
Another idea and probably the one I wish to pursue is having each one of these hidden divs in its own page that way it is easier to manage individually.
Any ideas or methods to accomplish this?
Also the way is current an asp.net page which I plan to convert to asp mvc eventually which allows the loading of views with jquery.
So i can place each div into a view and manage them that way.
Until then any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before using JavaScript templates. Each div would get it's own HTML file that would be loaded into the DOM as needed. You can also pass data to these templates and manipulate it before inserting it. Anther handy use is caching each page after it's called.

I just used a simple template engine for this
http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/